# ttyUSBx data stalls, usbmon/wireshark shows data

Tags: linux, usb, wireshark, tty

I am working on developing a sensor platform based on a raspberry pi running raspbian and an analog/digital converter (ADC) connected via USB. The ADC should be providing data at 128Hz, and does so fairly reliably. For my purposes this data is time sensitive, so having reasonably accurate timestamps on the 128Hz data is important.

I am using ttyUSBx to interact with the ADC. I have found an issue where the data seems to stall and then rush in at a later point. For example: Data is received at 128Hz, and then a “stall” happens. For about 0.05 seconds, I don’t see any data received. Then after the “stall” ends all of the data I expected during the last 0.05 seconds shows up very quickly (faster than 128Hz) and then the data is received as expected.

As part of my debugging efforts, I used wireshark with usbmon to monitor the frames being received from the ADC. These logs appear to show the frames being received without any stalling. This has left me very confused. I am not experienced enough with how Linux handles USB to solve this issue, so I’m not sure how to move from here (although not for lack of trying). I am aware that there is a difference between the TTY layer and the general USB layer in the Linux kernel, but I am not sure why usbmon is able to see things that TTY does not.

I have also done some stress testing using stress-ng on the system, and found that when the I/O is saturated that this issue also comes up. I am not sure if they are related but this is the only other thing I have found to be consistently similar to my problem.

I think it is also worth noting that the system clock is being trained by NTPsec using a GPS, and that I have ruled out any NTP updating or slewing as part of the issue. I have not seen any correlation between the NTP updates (including jumps) and this problem.

My goal here is to find a way to receive the data at a consistent 128Hz, so I am open to any solution that allows me to do that on my current platform within raspbian. Really, any information on how TTY might be working differently than usbmon would be appreciated.

EDIT:
Here's some extra information to help clairfy the problem. Please let me know if I can provide anything else to claify it further.

All code for this project is written in C++.

The serial port is opened with `O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NDELAY` pointed at /dev/ttyUSBx (usually 0 or 1) and configured with the following:

```
    tio.c_iflag = IGNBRK | IGNPAR;
    tio.c_oflag = 0;
    tio.c_cflag = CS8 | CREAD | CLOCAL;
    tio.c_lflag = 0;
    tio.c_cc[VTIME] = 1;
    tio.c_cc[VMIN]  = 0;
```

Here’s the relevant code:

```
int driver_serial::init() {


    //
    // Open the serial port device file.
    //

    // O_RDWR   - Open for reading and writing.
    // O_NOCTTY - The port never becomes the controlling terminal for 
    //            the process.
    // O_NDELAY - Use no-blocking I/O. Ignore control characters and 
    //            transmit raw data- REMOVED as it overwrites VMIN and VTIME

    if ((fd = open((char *) port.c_str(), O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NDELAY)) < 0) {
        std::cerr << "Couldn't open serial port " << port << std::endl;
        return (-1);
    }

    //
    // Check if we are indeed dealing with a serial device.
    //

    if (!isatty(fd)) {
        fprintf(stderr,"The specified port does not correspond "
                "to a serial device!\n");
        return (-1);
    }

    //
    // Get the current configuration of the serial interface.
    //

    if (tcgetattr(fd, &tio) < 0) {
        std::cerr << "Could not get confiuration of serial port " << port
                << std::endl;
        return (-1);
    }

    //
    // Set the input flags (c_iflag).
    //

    // IGNBRK    -  Ignore break conditions
    // IGNPAR    -  Ignore parity errors
    tio.c_iflag = IGNBRK | IGNPAR;

    //
    // Set the output flags (c_oflag)
    //

    // No output processing.
    tio.c_oflag = 0;

    //
    // Set the flag constants (c_cflag)
    //

    // CS8     - Eight bits per byte
    // CREAD   - Enable to receive data
    // CLOCAL  - Ignore modem control lines
    tio.c_cflag = CS8 | CREAD | CLOCAL;

    //   
    // Set the local flags (c_lflag)
    //

    // No higher-level input processing, non-canonical.
    tio.c_lflag = 0;

    //
    // Set some special characters (c_cc).
    //

    // Wait max. 10 ms for one byte to receive.
    tio.c_cc[VTIME] = 1;
    tio.c_cc[VMIN]  = 0;

    //
    // Write serial port configuration
    //
    if (tcsetattr(fd, TCSADRAIN, &tio) < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr,"Serial port configuration could not be written!");
        return (-1);
    }

    //
    // Flush the serial port buffer
    //
    tcflush(fd, TCIOFLUSH);

    // Serial port successfully configured.
    return (0);

}
```

This gets passed to a receive function, which continuously reads from the serial port and inserts it into a buffer called `buf` until it finds a termination character. The timestamp for the data is saved when the first character is received. Here’s the relevant code:

```
int driver_serial::receive(char *buf, int buflen, double timeout,
        struct timespec *recv_time) {

    // Received char
    unsigned char c;

    // Counter for received termination characters
    int n = 0;
    // Counter for received characters
    int i = 0;

    // Starting time and current time
    struct timespec start_time, end_time;

    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //
    // Receive data until termination characters arrive.
    //
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    // Empty the buffer (may be dangerous if buflen is longer than the buffer)
    memset(buf, 0, buflen);

    // Timeout in nanoseconds
    if (timeout>0){
        clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &start_time);
    }

    // Repeat loop until all termination characters have been received
    while (n < termlen) {
        
        //
        // Check for timeout
        //
        if (timeout > 0) {
            clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &end_time);
            if ( (end_time.tv_sec-start_time.tv_sec)+end_time.tv_nsec/1e9 >=
                start_time.tv_nsec/1e9+timeout ) {
                fprintf(stderr, "Warning: Timeout. No response received.\n");
                return (-1);
            }
        }
        
        // 
        // We receive something. Let's check. 
        //
        if (read(fd, &c, 1) > 0) {

            // A correct termination character has arrived
            if (c == term[n]) {
                n++;
                buf[i++] = c;
            }
            // A character was received
            else if (!ignnul || c != 0) {
                // Time of first received character is saved
                if (i == 0) {
                    clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, recv_time);
                }
                // Reset termination check if not all characters are received in a row
                if (n > 0) {
                    i -= n;
                    buf[i] = 0;
                    n = 0;
                }
                // Save character to buffer
                buf[i++] = c;
            }
            // Check for buffer overrun
            if (i >= buflen) {
                flush();
                fprintf(stderr, "Warning: %d characters received."
                                "Buffer overrun.\n", buflen);
                return (-1);
            }

        }

    }

    // 
    // Receive was successful if we arrive here.
    //

    // Set zero character correctly to ignore termination characters.
    buf[i - n] = 0;

    return (0);

}
```

The `receive` buffer passes to the main loop, which receives the response from the `receive` function and parses it. This data is then put into a secondary buffer (`buffer`) to be used elsewhere in the program. This also inserts the timestamp from the `receive` function into the data object. Here’s the relevant code:

```
int driver_obs_obsdaq::freerun(double freq) {

    // Time of measurement
    struct timespec recv_time, time;
    // The vector data
    data_obs_vector data(5);
    // The receive buffer
    char buf[200]="";
    // Data parser function
    int (driver_obs_obsdaq::*parse_data)(data_obs_vector* data, char* buf);


    // Infinite loop
    while (1) {

        // Receive data
        if (receive(buf, sizeof(buf), 0, &recv_time) >= 0) {

            // Set the time
            data.set_time(&recv_time);

            // Parse data from answer
            if ( (this->*parse_data)(&data, buf) >= 0 ){

                            // Calibrate the measurement/ASCII
                            driver_obs::cal->calibrate(&data);

            }

            // Write measurement to buffer
            buffer->put(&data);

        }

    }

    return (0);

}
```

After we have a buffer of data objects, they are eventually used in other functions for data processing and filtering. One of the simple results is just writing it to a file, which is how I noticed my issue in the first place. The data I write to the file has the stalls, but usbmon doesn’t appear to have this issue. From my understanding, my problem likely happens before the receive code ever gets a character to read the first character, since that’s also where I get a timestamp.

Comment: Without actual code and vague descriptions we're left to guess what you mean.  *"For about 0.05 seconds, I don’t see any data received"* -- How do *"you see"*?  How do you timestamp the data; in userspace?  How is the serial terminal configured, i.e. the termios settings?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I apologize for the vagueness, I’m just not entirely sure what is relevant and what isn’t, so I appreciate the clarifying questions. I’ve edited the original with some extra information. Thank you for taking a look!

Answer (score 0):

[Consider posting future programming questions to Stackoverflow.com.]

The likeliest cause of the "stalling" is (normal) processing scheduling and/or flawed timing data.  Your program as constructed is a CPU hog.  A read syscall from userspace merely fetches bytes from a system buffer.  Rather than efficiently waiting (aka block) for data, your program repeatedly polls the system (termios) buffer.
Beware that timestamping in userspace is inherently inaccurate.
The termios initialization is incomplete and not portable.
A rewrite/redesign is needed.

---

Beware that using clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, ...) to measure time intervals is not reliable.  The CLOCK_REALTIME is subject to adjustments for synchronization with wall time.  See [Difference between CLOCK_REALTIME and CLOCK_MONOTONIC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3523442/difference-between-clock-realtime-and-clock-monotonic).

---

Your program uses non-blocking I/O, and then proceeds to repeatedly issue **read()** (of just a single byte) until data is returned.  That is inefficient code that can waste the process's "time slice", and can introduce noticeable process suspension while the OS schedules other processes.  See [Completely Fair Scheduler](https://www.linuxjournal.com/node/10267).

Blocking mode will enable use of the termios VMIN and VTIME parameters to refine when a **read()** will return.  See [this answer to Blocking vs non-blocking Serial Read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25996171/linux-blocking-vs-non-blocking-serial-read/26006680#26006680) for a more details.
Instead of trying to read just one byte per syscall, try to fetch as much data as possible per syscall.  See [this answer to Parsing complete messages from serial port](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43280740/parsing-complete-messages-from-serial-port/43287464#43287464) for sample code.

---

> ... I am not sure why usbmon is able to see things that TTY does not.

Usbmon is capturing the data at a much lower level than your program in userspace.  Usbmon relies on special access (aka hooks) to the USB stacks in the kernel that precedes all the buffering and processing of using a *serial terminal*.
Study Figure 3 at [Linux serial drivers](http://www.linux.it/%7Erubini/docs/serial/serial.html).  The USB subsystem occupies the bottom layers of "Low-level driver" and "Hardware" in that diagram.
Your program acquires the data (that usbmon has already captured) only after several buffer copies and potential scheduling delays later.